# Kryonet Serialization Error

Tags: java, kryonet

Before anyone tries to tell me this is a duplicate I have tried the solutions on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22674663/how-to-send-objects-over-a-network-using-kryonet) and just about every other answer I could find.

My project builds fine in IntelliJ, passes all the tests I've setup, it even runs from inside IntelliJ just fine, as soon as I try to run the JAR built by maven I'm slapped in the face with several exceptions.

The class the code is pointing to:

```
package com.albion;

import com.albion.logging.Loggable;
import com.albion.packets.Packet;
import com.albion.packets.Packets;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Server;
import com.esotericsoftware.minlog.Log;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.logging.Level;

public class Main extends Loggable {
    protected static Integer PORT = 47532;

    protected static byte[] key = { /* contents omitted for obvious reasons */ };

    protected static Server server;
    protected static Controller controller;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.set(Log.LEVEL_DEBUG);
        server = new Server();
        server.bind(PORT);

        try {
            controller = new Controller();
            controller.setVisible(true);
            ClientManager.setController(controller);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            getLog().log(Level.SEVERE, "Error creating a new Controller instance: ", ex.getCause());
        }

        handlers();
        register();

        server.start();
    }

    private static void handlers() {
        getLog().info("Creating new PacketHandler");
        PacketHandler handler = new PacketHandler(controller);

        getLog().info("Creating new ClientListener");
        ClientListener listener = new ClientListener(handler);

        getLog().info("Adding listeners to server");
        server.addListener(listener);
    }

    private static void register() {

        getLog().info("Registering data types");

        server.getKryo().register(UUID.class);
        server.getKryo().register(byte[].class);
        server.getKryo().register(Packet.class);
        server.getKryo().register(String.class);
        server.getKryo().register(HashMap.class);
        server.getKryo().register(Packets.class);
        server.getKryo().register(String[].class);

    }
}
```

According to the exception I see when this is run via command prompt the problem lies on line 31 which would be:

```
    server = new Server();
```

The stack trace in command prompt is as follows:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create serializer "com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer" for class: com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.FrameworkMessage$RegisterTCP
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.factories.ReflectionSerializerFactory.makeSerializer(ReflectionSerializerFactory.java:48)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.factories.ReflectionSerializerFactory.makeSerializer(ReflectionSerializerFactory.java:26)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.newDefaultSerializer(Kryo.java:351)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.getDefaultSerializer(Kryo.java:344)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.register(Kryo.java:365)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.KryoSerialization.<init>(KryoSerialization.java:31)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.KryoSerialization.<init>(KryoSerialization.java:23)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Server.<init>(Server.java:91)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Server.<init>(Server.java:73)
    at com.albion.Main.main(Main.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.factories.ReflectionSerializerFactory.makeSerializer(ReflectionSerializerFactory.java:35)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create UnsafeFieldFactory
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.getUnsafeFieldFactory(FieldSerializer.java:408)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.newMatchingCachedField(FieldSerializer.java:375)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.newCachedField(FieldSerializer.java:343)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.createCachedFields(FieldSerializer.java:307)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.rebuildCachedFields(FieldSerializer.java:239)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.rebuildCachedFields(FieldSerializer.java:156)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.<init>(FieldSerializer.java:133)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.UnsafeCachedFieldFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.getUnsafeFieldFactory(FieldSerializer.java:405)
    ... 20 more
```

As mentioned before I'm using maven to build this project, I'm using the maven-shade-plugin in order to shade the kryonet files into my JAR.

Here is my POM.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.albion</groupId>
    <artifactId>Server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>Server</artifactId>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.albion</groupId>
        <artifactId>ServerCommons</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <index>true</index>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Main-Class>com.albion.Main</Main-Class>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that minimizeJar in the maven's shade plugin was responsible for this. 
Removed that option in a last-ditch attempt to fix things and everything works like clockwork.